# Half area of trapezoid keeping slope angle constant

Tags: geometry

I have a trapezoid:

[image]

Suppose its area is $A$.

Keeping $x$ and $a$ constant, what is the value of $y$ for $\frac{A}{2}$?

Or, more generally, what is the value of $y$ for an arbitrary multiple of $A$, i.e. $Ab$?

Comment: The value of $y$ in terms of $x$ and $A$ so that $A$ is half the original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area is the sum of the areas of a rectangle and a triangle:
$$A=x y + \frac{y(y \tan(a))}{2}$$
This can easily be solved for $y$ as a function of $A$:
$$y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+2\tan(a)A}}{\tan(a)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The area ofthe rectangle is obviously $xy$. The length $z$ can be computed in terms of $y$ and $a$ by using Al Kashi's formula, so you can get the area of the triangle. Thus, there is a simple formula to express $A$ as a function of $x$, $y$ and $a$. With this formula, you can express $y$ as a function of $x$, $a$ and $A$, which answers your question.